# Why is my code returning incorrect keys at a few stages?

Tags: java

Why am I getting discrepencies in the data returned like. It works fine till 3, then boom, it messes up until the end. What I am doing is simple. I am taking values from a txt file with id,name and matching the ids with another txt file that has name,name to make it appear like id, id, as you can see below. However, it doesn't work as you'd expect. The matching is being done fine till a point it messes up.

```
0,1
1,3
0,2
0
3,0,4
2
3,0
4,2
4,1
2,




while ((output2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {

    String[] vv = output2.split(",");
    String value1 = vv[0];
    String value2 = vv[1];

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        int key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
                                    //System.out.println(key+","+value);

        if ((value1.equals(value))) {
            System.out.print(key + ",");

        }

        if ((value2.equals(value))) {
            System.out.print(key + "\n");
        }

    }

}
```

Data

```
ids.txt

0,Triple H
1,John Cena
2,Megan Fox
3,The Undertaker
4,Pamela Anderson
5,The Rock
```

text.txt

```
Triple H,John Cena
John Cena,The Undertaker,
Triple H,Megan Fox
The Undertaker,Triple H
```

Comment: Can you put the 2 txt files here (just the first messing lines) ?

Comment: Hey, I did. Check the edit.

Comment: Though this won't fix your problem, remember that you can just use if (vv[0].equals(value)) instead of making the variable called value1 and checking what that equals.

Comment: Is there a way to not use TWO ifs, maybe that solves it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

at your fourth entry

```
String value2 = vv[1];
```

`vv[1]` would be null as there is no value after first comma.

EDIT:

in your fourth entry

```
The Undertaker,Triple H
```

`value2 (i.e. Triple H)` is matched in the `first iteration` of the loop at `zeroth position`, so it is printed with a `\n`, 
then `entry 3 is matched` in the `4rd iteration` and it is printed on `next line with a comma`

that is why you are getting output like

```
0
3,0,4
```

Comment: you always need to check for value1 first, then when you have found it reset the loop and check for value2, you can do it easily in two separate loops, first for value 1, then for value2 or do something as @ryknow suggested in his answer

Comment: I fixed it by using two for loops.

Comment: @AliGajani cool,now that you've got the answer, please mark one of the answers (mine or ryknow) as the correct answer, for future viewers.

Comment: Did, dont forget to upvote my question so others may find it helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple solution would be to hold onto the matched values until after the for loop.

```
while ((output2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] vv = output2.split(",");
    String value1 = vv[0];
    String value2 = vv[1];
    int key1 = -1;
    int key2 = -1;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        int key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
                                    //System.out.println(key+","+value);

        if ((value1.equals(value))) {
            key1 = key;
        }

        if ((value2.equals(value))) {
            key2 = key;
        }

    }
    if (key1 != -1 && key2 != -1) {
        System.out.println(key1 + ", " + key2 + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I fixed it using two loops

Comment: My mistake.  You have to use Integer or set it to a value that you won't have an id for like -1.